# How to create a blank chart in .net 4

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, charts

I've got a working chart (ASP.NET/VB.NET), over some selected periods of time it has no data, this is expected.

When I select a period of time where there is no data I get no chart displayed, just a rectangle of the background colour of the chart.

What I want is to still display the titles, x and y axes etc when there is no data, just an empty chart.

I toyed with the idea of adding a data point outside the time scale of the chart and this worked, I then got an empty graph, but there must be a cleaner way to achieve this. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever mind a clean way of doing this? I've played with hiding/showing the chart, but an empty chart with the axis displayed would be ideal...

Comment: No I haven't found a clean way of doing this. I ended up adding a data point outside the time range displayed on the chart. It works but it still feels messy.

Comment: I found adding a title (with visible=false) to be simple, then catching empty data sets on the datasource's `Selected` event (and toggle the "empty" title accordingly).

Answer (score 0):

Try to override or rewrite the

> Chart.OnPrePaint

method then implement your custom render logic.

[Reference:MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.chart.onprepaint.aspx)